# Disable java doc auto formatting in Intellij Idea. 2019

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style, javadoc

I want my javadoc to look like this:

```
/**
* Date 10/01/2019
*
* Given a directed graph, find all strongly connected components in this graph.
* We are going to use Kosaraju's algorithm to find strongly connected       component.
*
* Algorithm
* Create a order of vertices by finish time in decreasing order.
* Reverse the graph
* Do a DFS on reverse graph by finish time of vertex and created strongly connected
* components.
*
* Runtime complexity - O(V + E)
* Space complexity - O(V)
*
* References
* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component
* http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/
*/
```

But unfortunately my javadoc gets auto formatted to :

```
/**
* Given a directed acyclic graph, find all connected components in the graph.       We will be using
* Kosaraju’s algorithm for finding all connected components
*
* <p>Algorithm :
*
* <p>Do DFS on the graph, mark the adjacent vertices as visited and order the visited vertex
*
* <p>Reverse the graph - transpose<>
*
* <p>Do DFS on the reversed graph, by pop- ing elements from the stack and marking them as visited
*
* <p>Complexity:
*
* <p>Runtime - O(V+E) for DFS
*
* <p>Space = O(V) for the stack and visited vertices
*
* <p>Date : 15/02/20
*
*
* <p>Referances : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpgcYiky7uw
* https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/
*/
```

If I add a line break manually and start writing on the next line, during code format the two lines gets merged into one. The only way that I can write on the next line is by adding two newlines, so during code format ide adds

to the new line

Say suppose I want to split

"Do DFS on the graph, mark the adjacent vertices as visited and order the visited vertex"

into two lines, but as soon as I reformat my code the two lines gets merged into once

I am using google-java-format for code formatting.

I tried modifying Code Style -> Java -> JavaDoc options but somehow the changes. does't  seem to work

Answer (score 0):

To avoid line merging in JavaDoc, you may open (Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | JavaDoc) and unmark the **”Wrap at right margin”** checkbox.